# silverlight 4 project into a single solution or seperate?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

i started off with a new silverlight 4 project in a seperate solution while my web app, database, bll/dal and web services are in a seperate solution. I quickly ran into the whole clientaccesspolicy.xml problem when silverlight client tried connecting to my other solution running in http://localhost:4415/ but that just doesn't work with cassinni.

What would be best practices for this silverlight app and the rest of my projects (database, web services, web site, bll, dal) in the other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just put all of the projects into a single solution, the web app becomes the host for the Silverlight project so that its builds end up in the web app ClientBin folder.